# WinForm - DevExpress theme

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I use using the DevExpress 17.2 component, how can I save the theme for the entire application? I use RibbonForm, I would like to save the settings of the selected theme in Properties.Settings. And in the subsequent opening of the application remains the same topic as the user chose ...

Answer (score 3):

You can save the current skin name to the Application Settings as described in the [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings) Microsoft document. To access this skin name, use the [DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.SkinName.property) property. When your app is loaded, read the save skin name from the app settings and assign it to the mentioned static property.

Comment: OP -- if this answer satisfied your need, you should mark it as correct so future users with the same issue will know this question has a working solution